# How to add Calendar Control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, dll

I added refference to PresentationFramework.dll, because there was Controls.Calendar with DisplayMode property. But it is simply not a Forms.Control, and I can not add it to my FlowLayoutPanel. Is there any way to be able use Calendar in simple Windows Forms program?

Comment: MonthCalendar is not that hard to find in the toolbox, keep looking.

Comment: @HansPassant how can I change its mode?

Comment: @HansPassant how can I set it to be able pick only months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calender control is a WPF control.

You can add to it your windows form by using ElementHost.

You can find element host in

**Toolbox->WPF Interopability->ElementHost.**

Now you can add any WPF control as said below. (May be in form load)

```
Calendar basicCalendar = new Calendar();

basicCalendar.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2009, 1, 10);
basicCalendar.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2009, 4, 18);
basicCalendar.DisplayDate = new DateTime(2009, 3, 15);
basicCalendar.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2009, 2, 15);

//Adding your WPF control
elementHost1.Child = basicCalendar;
```